# Network connection was lost NSURLConnection

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

This error is printed every time I attempt a connection. No idea why it cant connect to the server. Built a simple java application and it worked fine. Ive been surfing StackOverflow for days trying to figure this out. Tried multiple API's and somethings just not right. If you need more code, or have any further questions let me know. Please help. :(

> 2013-08-29 21:56:55.946 panic[15054:70b] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0xa779a30
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=`http://54.221.224.251/`,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=`http://54.221.224.251/`,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0xa611130 "The network connection was lost."}

Here is my code that sets up the request:

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.221.224.251"];
    [urlPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *stringdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phash=%@",name,email,phash];
    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:stringdata];
    [postData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;
    [connection start];
```

Here is my code thats supposed to handle responses from the php server.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}
/*
 if there is an error occured, this method will be called by connection
 */
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@" , error);
}

/*
 if data is successfully received, this method will be called by connection
 */
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"WORKED!");
}
```

Comment: can you make a successful connection with a browser? as your stringdata looks like a GET request string, but you want to do a POST... (i am just a bit confused)

Comment: I can make a successful connection from a browser. It shouldn't really matter though right? Because a network connection was lost error wouldn't be thrown, it'd get like a 500 error.

Comment: Another thing thats weird, is that if I set the domain to google.com, it works, so I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: maybe your url encoding is not done properly, just try stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding on urlpath and postdata (fyi it would be good to add Content-Length to your request as well)

Comment: Still gives network connection was lost, but I didn't add Content-Length, not sure where to add it. I also pasted the updated code above with the stringByAddingPercentEncoding, just to make sure I did everything right.

Comment: '[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];' you are not assigning your encoded postData and urlpath into a var. it sould be something like 'NSString *encoded = [val stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just putting ampersands, I needed to add them in like so for the stringData.

```
NSString *stringdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&amp;email=%@&amp;phash=%@",name,email,phash];
```

This fixed my problem.